# How to export data from c# console application to Excel

Tags: c#, excel

i have some rows and columns in c# console output, i want to export this to excel.any advice? Thanks

Comment: Do you have the rows in code? or do you just want to copy-paste the output from the console?

Comment: Some more info about your data would be helpful for us to give you help - but you could output the data to CSV which you can open in Excel. If your data is in a DataGrid here is a quick method of doing that : http://www.dylansweb.com/2015/06/wpf-datagrid-the-easy-way-to-export-to-csv/

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the **ClosedXML** library. Here's a neat example:

```
XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();
DataTable dt = new DataTable() { TableName = "New Worksheet" };
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

//input data
var columns = new[] { "column1", "column2", "column3" };
var rows = new object[][] 
{
     new object[] {"1", 2, false },
     new object[] { "test", 10000, 19.9 }
};

//Add columns
dt.Columns.AddRange(columns.Select(c => new DataColumn(c)).ToArray());

//Add rows
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}

//Convert datatable to dataset and add it to the workbook as worksheet
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
workbook.Worksheets.Add(ds);

//save
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string savePath = Path.Combine(desktopPath, "test.xlsx");
workbook.SaveAs(savePath, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I utilized the `EPPlus` Library from Nuget.  Below is my dynamic implementation, that serves my needs.  You can find simpler examples in their documentation.  But that would allow you to actually create row / colum based on your Poco.

You could utilize a method such as:

```
    public void WriteFile<THeader, TEntity>(THeader header, params TEntity[] contents)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(FileInformation.FullName))
            File.Create(FileInformation.FullName).Close();

        using (var excel = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(FileInformation.Name);
            CreateExcelWorksheetHeader(worksheet, header);

            var row = 2;
            Dictionary<int, object> mapping = BuildTableMap(worksheet, 1);
            foreach (TEntity content in contents)
            {
                MapEntityToRow(worksheet, mapping, row, content);
                row++;
            }

            excel.SaveAs(FileInformation);
        }
    }

    private static void CreateExcelWorksheetHeader<THeader>(ExcelWorksheet worksheet, THeader entity)
    {
        var index = 1;
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(THeader).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[1, index].Value = property.GetValue(entity, null);
            index++;
        }
    }

    private static void MapEntityToRow<TEntity>(ExcelWorksheet worksheet, Dictionary<int, object> table, int row, TEntity entity)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> properties = ObjectMapper.GetPropertyNameAndAttribute<TEntity>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, object> column in table)
        {
            var matchColumnToProperty = properties.SingleOrDefault(property => string.Compare(property.Key, (string)column.Value, true) == 0).Key;
            var matchColumnToAttribute = properties.SingleOrDefault(property => string.Compare(property.Value, (string)column.Value, true) == 0).Value;

            if (matchColumnToProperty != null)
                worksheet.Cells[row, column.Key].Value =
                    typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(matchColumnToProperty).GetValue(entity, null);

            if (matchColumnToAttribute != null)
                worksheet.Cells[row, column.Key].Value =
                    typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(properties.SingleOrDefault(property => string.Compare(property.Value, matchColumnToAttribute, true) == 0).Key)
                    .GetValue(entity, null);
        }
    }
```